# Python sample without 0

Tags: python, random

I need to sample k numbers in [-n,-1] union [1,n] without replacement. Why doesn't this code work?

```
random.sample(range(-n,n+1).remove(0),k)
```

I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/random.py", line 319, in sample
    n = len(population)
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

Answer (score 1):

`remove` is an inplace operation. It modifies the list, and returns none. That's why you are seeing the error. You should create the list separately and pass it to `sample`:

```
>>> l = range(-n, n+1)
>>> l.remove(0)
>>> random.sample(l, k)
```

If you want to do it in one statement, you could create the two parts of the range separately and add them.

```
>>> random.sample(range(-n, 0) + range(1, n+1), k)
```

Comment: Can this be done within the call to `sample`? That is, `sample(some code,k)`?